# How change the height of the UIScrollView's content when software keyboard is pushed upward

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a view with a textview and a button like in any typical messaging app. When the keyboard is presented, the textview and button are pushed upwards as well but the content is pushed upwards off the screen where I don't see the top end of it but when I force scroll down I see it creeping down and it springs upwards when I let go. I have illustrated the problem I'm having with a quick sketch, the third screen is the desired behavior.

I have this view in a .xib file. I have a view -> ScrollView -> contentView (which has a the table and the textview and button)

[image]

I registered the keyboard notifications and here's the code for the show/hide methods

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];

} 

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
   NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];

   CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

   // the hardcoded 49 is the height of the uitabbar 
   UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-keyboardSize.height+49, 0.0, keyboardSize.height-49, 0.0);
   self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
   self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];

 }


- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
   UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
   self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

   [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this line in keyboardWasShown method

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-keyboardSize.height+49, 0.0, keyboardSize.height-49, 0.0);
```

Where you top Edge inset is -ve, becouse 49 - keyboardSize (which is appx 256). Replace it with this :

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.height-49), 0.0);
```

Play with calculation best suite to you. Hope this work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification{

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:true];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work for me. The textview and button are moving with the scroll view.

Comment: That doesn't work either. What i'm trying to do is to fit the scrolview between the software keyboard the top of the view right under the navigationbar